# Merge PDF files from several folders using the folder names as chapters and file names as sub-chapters

Tags: linux, pdf, merge, user-folders

I have a folder with sunfolders full of PDF files. I need to combine them in a way such that will use the folder names as chapters and file names as sub-chapters. How can it be achieved? Standalone app is preferred. Although using something in Python or equivalent will work.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @Jounathaen Linux.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, but my idea would be to use latex. You can load existing pdf into it, and of course create a table of contents etc

Comment: @Jounathaen I meant I wanted to do it using some algorithm. So that I do not have to add everything in manually.

Comment: @Jounathaen I have access to Windows too if it helps.

Comment: Doesn't sound like the best solution, but you can use a simple bash/python script to create such an latex document. something like:
`for x in *.pdf; do echo "\includepdf[pages={1}]{$x}" >> myla.tex; done`

Comment: @Jounathaen But that won't add the chapter names, right?

Comment: Not in this form, but you can easily add other Latex commands in the for loop like `\section{$x}. I havn't tested the code, it's just an idea